# How to Send Email Verification to a Personal Email Using Firebase Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am making a system with Email Verification but i want to send the Registered email to a personal Email
(so he/she can only verify the user for security) address instead sending to the user. is there any way to do that in java android studio? i am using a firebase database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused about what you mean when you say "the registered email to a personal email", but with FirebaseAuth, when a user is signed in with `FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`, you should be able to take the FirebaseUser that it returns and call `FirebaseUser.sendEmailVerification()`

You can then use `FirebaseUser.isEmailVerified()` to check if the user has verified their email, and allow or deny certain functions in your app based on that.

Comment: i mean instead of sending the email verification to the registered user, the email verification will instead send to a specific email address so that he/she will be the only one to verify that registered user. like for example to my email. and i will be the only one who can verify a user registration. i just want to use it for security. i dunno if that is possible.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I don't believe that is possible to do with FirebaseAuth. I'm not too sure it's a necessity though, as having the user verify their own email is usually secure enough. Plus having to verify everyone yourself could get overwhelming.

Comment: thank you for the information. it is a great help! :D